# Is a Zotac Geforce GT 220 supported?

Tags: 11.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am planning to install Ubuntu 11.04 on a machine using Zotac Geforce GT 220.

Does anyone know if this card is supported?

Thanks

Comment: You might get lucky [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification)

Comment: This specifies certified systems - not holding information on specific graphic hardware brand.hmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the NVIDIA readme in `/usr/share/doc/nvidia-current/README.txt.gz` this card is supported (From Appendix A:)

```
A1. NVIDIA GEFORCE GPUS

NVIDIA GPU product                    Device PCI ID*     VDPAU features
----------------------------------    ---------------    ---------------

GeForce GT 220M                       0x0654             A
GeForce GT 220                        0x0A20             C
```

So after you install the [Additional drivers tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-proprietary-drivers) will prompt you asking to install these drivers and then you should be set.

Comment: @Jorge - my resolution is still bigger after installing the driver - I can now have the 3D effects that comes with 11.4 which is awesome but when I try changing the resolutions via Monitor Prefs.- it indicates 'Unknown'. Do you know what could be happening?

Comment: The monitor can accept max resolution of 1920x1200 but the max resolution I can see in Monitor pref. is 1200x640. Hmm!

Comment: @Bitmap You probably need to run the nvidia pref tool, not the built in one. (Search around the nvidia tag to see if someone's asked how to use it, if not, ask another question and we'll move on to that problem.

Comment: @Jorge when you said **not the built in one**, did you mean not the one located at `Applications->System Tools->NVIDIA X` or essentially what you get after running `gksudo nvidia-settings`?!

Comment: @Bitmap By built in I mean the generic "Monitors" tool in the system prefs, you need to run the nvidia tool (aka. nvidia-settings) which is also in the prefs menu.

Answer (score 1):

First, make a live CD of natty, run it, then
You can check using the following command in the terminal :

`/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`

Comment: I have not installed it yet - do not want to go through the setup only to conclude it is not supported, hence this initial research. I want to establish it is ok first. Cheers.

Comment: if you want you can try a live cd... right? you can check it there... i suppose

Comment: @Bitmap, live CD isn't the same as installation - it basically runs from the CD directly onto the RAM with no changes to your PC.

Comment: I don't think this will work, he'd need to install the OS, the nvidia driver in order to pass the test, otherwise he'd be running the nouveau driver and that'll probably fail.

Comment: Your guide is very useful.